# iOS authentication process

Tags: ios, security, authentication

I am working on an app which needs the authentication. The backend is built with Flask python, and I am using POST request with a JSON to send the username and password. There are two questions I have actually.

First one, is it unsafe to authenticate with POST and JSON?

Second one, how can I keep the status of log in. I mean, like Facebook App, once user logged in, they don't have to input the password again even the app is restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with sending your auth credentials with POST, in fact, that's what you should be doing, never send these information via GET

As for how to keep the status, check out [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/) on the class to store your cookies, then check if they exist.

Also, I assume you know the HTTP status code as well? Just to give you more info, just because your cookies exists doesn't mean the user is also logged in, for example, cookies may be expired (time length depends on your server configuration). So in that case you might want to return status error 4xx. [HTTP Status Documentation](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html), and maybe presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true).